# Atomically share(without a mutex) boost::intrusive_ptr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I know boost has atomic_shared_ptr which can be used with a shared_ptr.

But is there a way to do something similar with boost::intrusive_ptr ?

i.e. is it possible to share boost::intrusive_ptr across one writer/multiple reader threads WITHOUT using mutexes ?

**Back ground :**

Unfortunately, my workplace allows only till C++11 (does NOT allow using C++20 yet). [std::atomic_store](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)  functions in C++11 seems NOT efficient as they use mutexes under the hood(see Notes in mentioned link).

Also due to performance requirements new/delete happening in std/boost shared_ptr for Control Blocks is NOT preferred. Hence the need to use boost::intrusive_ptr.

Comment: you can do it without boost at all. with `std::shared_ptr` / `std::weak_ptr`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291791/does-weak-ptrs-lock-will-always-work-in-statement-instore-com-r-lock-i

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин, mentioned question is removed. std::shared_ptr mutable operations are NOT thread safe(hence the std::atomic(std::shared_ptr) in C++20).  Unfortunately, my workplace allows only till C++11 (does NOT allow using C++20 yet). std::atomic_store  functions in C++11 seems NOT efficient as they use mutexes under the hood. Also due to performance requirements new/delete happening in std/boost shared_ptr for Control Blocks is NOT preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is impossible (at least with C++11) as even boost::atomic_shared_ptr seems to use a boost::detail::spinlock for this.
ref : https://github.com/BeamMW/boost-linux/blob/master/boost/smart_ptr/atomic_shared_ptr.hpp